# Python-3.5 Matching up values in lists of dicts to combine 2

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.5

I'm new to Python and having issues combining my lists of dicts how I need them to be. They are zipping properly but as you can see it's not actually the order I need them to be. These are dynamic lists the two below are examples.

List 1: data_keys:

```
[{'id': 438, 'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'GreetingDefault'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}, 
{'id': 441,'title': "Route from 'DNISGreeting' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}, 
{'id': 440, 'title': "Route from 'GreetingDefault' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}, 
{'id': 436, 'title': "Route from 'Start' to 'GetCallerDetail'", 'pre_conditions': [], 'tc_steps': [{'expected': '', 'content': 'APN: 8552929487, HollyBrowser: , '}]}, 
{'id': 439, 'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'DNISGreeting'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}]
```

List 2 network_edges:

```
[{'to': 4891, 'id': 441, 'from': 4890}, {'to': 4888, 'id': 436, 'from': 4887}, {'to': 4889, 'id': 438, 'from': 4888}, {'to': 4891, 'id': 440, 'from': 4889}, {'to': 4890, 'id': 439, 'from': 4888}]
```

My code for the zip:

```
for d, n in zip(network_edges, data_keys):
    d['data'] = n
```

Current output:

```
[{'from': 4890, 'id': 441, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'GreetingDefault'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4891}, 
{'from': 4887, 'id': 436, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'DNISGreeting' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4888}, 
{'from': 4888, 'id': 438, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GreetingDefault' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4889}, 
{'from': 4889, 'id': 440, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'Start' to 'GetCallerDetail'", 'tc_steps': [{'expected': '', 'content': 'APN: 8552929487, HollyBrowser: , '}], 'pre_conditions': []}], 'to': 4891}, 
{'from': 4888, 'id': 439, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'DNISGreeting'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4890}]
```

What I need:

```
[{'from': 4890, 'id': 441, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'DNISGreeting' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4891}, 
{'from': 4887, 'id': 436, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'Start' to 'GetCallerDetail'", 'tc_steps': [{'expected': '', 'content': 'APN: 8552929487, HollyBrowser: , '}], 'pre_conditions': []}], 'to': 4888}, 
{'from': 4888, 'id': 438, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'GreetingDefault'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4889}, 
{'from': 4889, 'id': 440, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GreetingDefault' to 'HOOCheck'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4891}, 
{'from': 4888, 'id': 439, 'data': [{'title': "Route from 'GetCallerDetail' to 'DNISGreeting'", 'tcs_cannot_route': "This edge cannot be routed: MenuPrompt/MenuPromptWC property 'Outputs' not found"}], 'to': 4890}]
```

Making myself crossed eyed as they seem to be lined up correctly but they are not. Your guidance is appreciated. Essentially the 'from' is the keyvalue i need to match with the "Route from string name in 'title'. I'll add more to the dicts if necessary for simplicity I would rather not bog them down if not necessary.

Comment: Can you copy-paste the exact results? You couldn't have gotten a dictionary with `'data': 'id': 4891` in it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 correct, updated with current results.

Comment: For `zip` only the order of the input iterables matters, so if your `data_keys` list isn't in the correct order in which you want to assign its items to the `network_edges` then it won't work. You need to find a different way to pick an item from `data_keys` for each item in `network_edges`.

Comment: There seems to be no overlap between data_keys and network_edges.  On what basis do you expect them to be paired?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I edited the data_keys and have included a matching 'id' key for both -- what I need is to match up the values of ids and then create a new list of dicts from the 2 list of dicts.